# Couldn't instantiate class org.jeecg.modules.activiti.service.Impl.TaskFinishedLicenser

Tags: activiti

I use this exclusive gateway to test activiti5.22.0.
When asking for leave for 1 day, go to the node above(one day check), and ask for leave for 2 days to go to the node below(two day check).

[image]

This error occurred when the request `/activiti/actTask/pass` was called during approval:

```
    2021-03-18 15:02:08.440 [http-nio-14000-exec-1] ERROR o.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext:171 - Error while closing command context
org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: couldn't instantiate class org.jeecg.modules.activiti.service.Impl.TaskFinishedLicenser
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.util.ReflectUtil.instantiate(ReflectUtil.java:137)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.helper.ClassDelegate.defaultInstantiateDelegate(ClassDelegate.java:242)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.helper.ClassDelegate.instantiateDelegate(ClassDelegate.java:232)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.helper.ClassDelegate.getExecutionListenerInstance(ClassDelegate.java:103)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.helper.ClassDelegate.notify(ClassDelegate.java:95)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:42)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:97)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:650)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:643)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.take(ExecutionEntity.java:460)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.take(ExecutionEntity.java:438)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.BpmnActivityBehavior.performOutgoingBehavior(BpmnActivityBehavior.java:140)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.BpmnActivityBehavior.performDefaultOutgoingBehavior(BpmnActivityBehavior.java:66)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.FlowNodeActivityBehavior.leave(FlowNodeActivityBehavior.java:44)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.AbstractBpmnActivityBehavior.leave(AbstractBpmnActivityBehavior.java:47)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.UserTaskActivityBehavior.signal(UserTaskActivityBehavior.java:228)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.signal(ExecutionEntity.java:417)
```

I just change

```
taskService.complete(id);
```

to

```
Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<String, Object>();
variables.put("days",days);
taskService.complete(id,variables);
```

This is the code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pass", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Result<Object> pass(@RequestParam String id,
                           @RequestParam String procInstId,
                           @RequestParam(required = false) String assignees,
                           @RequestParam(required = false) Integer priority,
                           @RequestParam(required = false) String comment,
                           @RequestParam(defaultValue = "false") Boolean sendMessage,
                           @RequestParam(defaultValue = "false") Boolean sendSms,
                           @RequestParam(defaultValue = "false") Boolean sendEmail,
                           @RequestParam(defaultValue = "true") int days,
                           HttpServletRequest request){

    String token = request.getHeader("X-Access-Token");
    if(StrUtil.isBlank(comment)){
        comment = "";
    }
    taskService.addComment(id, procInstId, comment);
    ProcessInstance pi = runtimeService.createProcessInstanceQuery().processInstanceId(procInstId).singleResult();
    Task task = taskService.createTaskQuery().taskId(id).singleResult();
    if(StrUtil.isNotBlank(task.getOwner())&&!("RESOLVED").equals(task.getDelegationState().toString())){
        String oldAssignee = task.getAssignee();
        taskService.resolveTask(id);
        taskService.setAssignee(id, oldAssignee);
    }
    Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    variables.put("days",days);
    taskService.complete(id,variables);
    ActBusiness actBusiness = actBusinessService.getById(pi.getBusinessKey());
    actBusinessService.updateBusinessStatus(actBusiness.getTableName(), actBusiness.getTableId(),task.getName());
    }
```

Where is wrong?

At present, two flow charts are used to solve the problem. The first flow chart corresponds to a 1-day leave, and the second flow chart corresponds to a 2-day leave. When an employee initiates a leave application, a dialog box will pop up and fill in the number of days of leave first. Then it will enter the corresponding process. Although this is not good, the problem can be solved temporarily.